# Keep data when iPhone app is updated (Monotouch)

Tags: database, xamarin.ios, app-store

I'm all new to this app coding but working with Monotouch makes it possible for me to actually do something :-)

I'm making an app that uses a database but I think it's likely that the app will evolve over time. If i submit an app to the appstore and users install it, it will over time store a lot of data.

Now, if I update the app and users get the update in app store what then? will the data be erased when they install the new version? 
and what if the DB schema changes?

thx
Nicolaj

Comment: No, it will not overwrite your data.  If your schema changes you will need to detect and handle that in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thx jason!

I also searched a bit more on my own and found this which also explains: [How to update SQLite DB on iPhone app update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767849/how-to-update-sqlite-db-on-iphone-app-update)