# How to Update my Existing SQLite DB during upgrade my app in iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I faced an issue with updating my `SQLite` DB during upgrade my app version.

**My Problem is:** I implemented an iOS app and my version is 1.0. And I have a DB structure which contains 2 tables, each table have 5 columns. And i uploaded the app in App Store. But in second edition I added some new tables and new columns in existing tables. Then I upgrade the version 2.0 in app store. That time when i use the app(without deleting old app from my device), app getting crashed due to new table and new columns are not updated in new Build.

So how can update the new db structure in existing app during upgrade the app in App store.

Please help me. I am struggling last 1 week.

Comment: You can do table changes programmatically.

Comment: How can I do it, I am just need that procedure. :)

Comment: At app launch, delete the database from the document directory and create new table programmatically or just add required fields/columns in that table.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the answer of  your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767849/how-to-update-sqlite-db-on-iphone-app-update)

Just alter thet tables for add column and create new tables if found old db version installed in app.

Thanks